# How To call/check values inside a method in UnitTest Angular4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I have 2 methods in my .ts file

```
 export class VehicleSaleInfoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
dealerBlock = true;
constructor(){}
ngOnInit() {}

runList() {
    this.dealerBlock = false;
 }

Dealer() {
    this.dealerBlock = true;
}

}
```

my .spec File

```
  it('should Show RunList Component exist', () => {
    expect(component.runList);
    // fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.dealerBlock, 'false').to.be.false;
});

it('should show DealerBlock Component exist', () => {
    expect(component.Dealer);
    expect(component.dealerBlock).to.be.true;
});
```

Error: 
 VehicleSaleInfoComponent
    × should Show RunList Component exist
      PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)
    false: expected true to be false

It will not pick the values inside the method... Any way to get values inside the method.

Comment: Am written this way..

it('should Show RunList Component exist', () => {
        component.dealerBlock = false;
        expect(component.runList);
        // fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.dealerBlock, 'false').to.be.false;
    });

But i dont know its the right way...

Comment: What `expect(component.runList)` is supposed to do?

Comment: expect(component.runList).to.be.exist;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specs above don't test the methods, so they fail. Methods should be called in order to be tested:

```
  it('should Show RunList Component exist', () => {
    component['dealerBlock'] = null; // avoid asserted type check
    component.runList();
    expect(component.dealerBlock).to.be.false;
  });
```

Comment: Ok thanks,

Otherwise we can use  like this ...? Right ..?

it('should Show RunList Component exist', () => {
   component.dealerBlock = false; 
    component.runList();
    expect(component.dealerBlock).to.be.false;
  });

Comment: Not really. Since you set it to `component.dealerBlock = false`, it's unclear if the method does something. That's why it was initially set to null.